# Database architecture/system for one-way multi-source replication into a central database

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design, replication

We're looking to build a large network of sensor nodes which all eventually goes into one centralized database. The current system (which has not been scaled up) consists of a single machine that contains a data translator which takes in the raw sensor data, writes the appropriate SQL call for a Postgres database, and executes the call to stuff data into a Postgres table.

I've setup remote machines to record sensor node data in remote locations. I would like to setup some system where I can push data from the remote locations to a central location in a reliable sort of manner. Since network connectivity is an issue, I can't just do remote database writes for fear of losing some of the time-series data.

I have a hack right now which kinda works; I have a script that periodically dumps the contents of a local postgres instance on the remote machine, copies it over to the master and then the master script re-integrates that data into it's database. The database on the remote machine is then wiped to prevent duplicates from happening the next time this "sync" happens.

Is there a good, industry standard way of accomplishing this? I need a pretty easy way of doing one-way multi-source replication into a central location. I've looked at using postgres with bucardo, but I haven't quite been successful. I'm not sure if I'm describing the system correctly, so feedback on that would be much appreciated also.

Comment: Londiste is usually used for this so long as you're OK with the results all going into separate tables. (You can use table inheritance to make them seem like a part of the same table on the receiving side.) I'm part of a team working on [a new approach that doesn't need triggers](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/BDR_User_Guide), but we haven't added unidirectional support yet, it's still multi-master only.